# How to extend bootstrap utilities classes in Nextjs Typescript project

Tags: sass, next.js, bootstrap-5

I have installed sass in next js and bootstrap, I can now access bootstrap variables and can reasign values of variables however when I try to extend a utility class from bootstrap it gives me error :

```
   SassError: The target selector was not found.
Use "@extend .text-center !optional" to avoid this error.
  ╷
9 │     @extend .text-center; //!optional;
  │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  styles\Step0.module.scss 9:2  root stylesheet
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Skipped not serializable cache item 'Compilation/modules|C:\MyApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\css-loader\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[1]!C:\MyApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-loader\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[2]!C:\MyApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\resolve-url-loader\index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[3]!C:\MyApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\sass-loader\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[4]!C:\MyApp\styles\Step0.module.scss': No serializer registered for SassError
<w> while serializing webpack/lib/cache/PackFileCacheStrategy.PackContentItems -> webpack/lib/NormalModule -> webpack/lib/ModuleBuildError -> SassError   
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Skipped not serializable cache item 'Compilation/modules|C:\MyApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\css-loader\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[0]!C:\MyApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-loader\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[1]!C:\MyApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\resolve-url-loader\index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[2]!C:\MyApp\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\sass-loader\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[3].use[3]!C:\MyApp\styles\Step0.module.scss': No serializer registered for SassError
<w> while serializing webpack/lib/cache/PackFileCacheStrategy.PackContentItems -> webpack/lib/NormalModule -> webpack/lib/ModuleBuildError -> SassError
```

the step0.module.scss is

```
.welcome {
    @extend .text-center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your Bootstrap classes before extending them. This will work for `text-center`:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

.welcome {
  @extend .text-center;
}
```

You may need to add other imports depending on which classes you're extending from.

[image]